# Adding record to 2013 ms access from 2012 vb.net not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I am creating a payroll program in Visual Studio 2012 using Visual Basic and a 2013 MS Access database. On my login form, the database is accessed to authenticate the login, and this works fine. On a form to add an employee, I am using the code below to add a record via textboxes. I am not getting any errors, but the database never updates with the new information. Any ideas?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class AddDriver

    Private Sub CancelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
        Dim ConnString As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\TruckingDatabase.mdb;")
        Dim SqlString As String = "Insert Into Drivers (ID, LastName, FirstName, License, Birthdate, TruckType, StartDate, TruckOwner) Values (@ID, @LastNameEntry, @FirstNameEntry, @LicenseNumberEntry, @BirthDate, @TruckType, @StartDate, @Owner)"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", ID.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", LastNameEntry.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", FirstNameEntry.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("License", LicenseNumberEntry.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TruckType", TruckType.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", StartDate.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TruckOwner", Owner.Text)
                conn.Open()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you need to execute the query

Comment: What @Plutonix said, specifically `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Also, **(1)** You have 8 parameter placeholders in your CommandText but you have only added 7 `.Parameter` objects. **(2)** If ID is an AutoNumber then you don't want to include it in your INSERT statement because the database engine will take care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get it to work by adding cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and adding in the missing parameter. I am not using AutoNumber, so I left this parameter in the code.